# Finding the value of $\cos(\frac{180^o}7)$ -- where am I wrong?

Tags: trigonometry

Let $\alpha=\frac{180^o}7$.

Consider that

$$\sin(3\alpha)=\sin(180^o-3\alpha)=\sin(4\alpha)$$

and

$$\cos(3\alpha)=-\cos(180^o-3\alpha)=-\cos(4\alpha)\text{.}$$

From $\sin(3\alpha)=\sin(4\alpha)$, we get

$$\sin(\alpha)\cos(2\alpha)+\sin(2\alpha)\cos(\alpha)=\sin(2\alpha)\cos(2\alpha)+\sin(2\alpha)\cos(2\alpha)$$
$$\cos(2\alpha)(\sin(\alpha)-\sin(2\alpha))=\sin(2\alpha)(\cos(2\alpha)-\cos(\alpha))$$
$$\cos(2\alpha)\sin(\alpha)(1-2\cos(\alpha))=2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)(2\cos^2(\alpha)-\cos(\alpha)-1)$$
$$\cos(2\alpha)(1-2\cos(\alpha))=2\cos(\alpha)(2\cos^2(\alpha)-\cos(\alpha)-1)$$
$$\cos(2\alpha)(1-2\cos(\alpha))=-2\cos^2(\alpha)(1-2\cos(\alpha))-2\cos(\alpha)$$
$$(\cos(2\alpha)+2\cos^2(\alpha))(1-2\cos(\alpha))=-2\cos(\alpha)$$
$$(\cos(2\alpha)+2\cos^2(\alpha))(2\cos(\alpha)-1)=2\cos(\alpha)$$
$$(4\cos^2(\alpha)-1)(2\cos(\alpha)-1)=2\cos(\alpha)$$
$$8\cos^3(\alpha)-4\cos^2(\alpha)-4\cos(\alpha)+1=0$$

From $\cos(3\alpha)=-\cos(4\alpha)$ we get

$$\cos(2\alpha)\cos(\alpha)-\sin(2\alpha)\sin(\alpha)=\sin(2\alpha)\sin(2\alpha)-\cos(2\alpha)\cos(2\alpha)$$
$$\cos(2\alpha)(\cos(2\alpha)+\cos(\alpha))=\sin(2\alpha)(\sin(2\alpha)+\sin(\alpha))$$
$$(2\cos^2(\alpha)-1)(2\cos^2(\alpha)+\cos(\alpha)-1)=\sin^2(2\alpha)+\sin(2\alpha)\sin(\alpha)$$
$$(2\cos^2(\alpha)-1)(2\cos^2(\alpha)+\cos(\alpha)-1)=1-\cos^2(2\alpha)+2\sin^2(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)$$
$$(2\cos^2(\alpha)-1)(2\cos^2(\alpha)+\cos(\alpha)-1)=1-(2\cos(\alpha)-1)^2+2(1-\cos^2(\alpha))\cos(\alpha)$$
$$4\cos^4(\alpha)+2\cos^3(\alpha)-4\cos^2(\alpha)-\cos(\alpha)+1=1-(4\cos^2(\alpha)-4\cos(\alpha)+1)+2\cos(\alpha)-2\cos^3(\alpha)$$
$$4\cos^4(\alpha)+2\cos^3(\alpha)-4\cos^2(\alpha)-\cos(\alpha)=-4\cos^2(\alpha)+4\cos(\alpha)-1+2\cos(\alpha)-2\cos^3(\alpha)$$
$$4\cos^4(\alpha)+4\cos^3(\alpha)-7\cos(\alpha)+1=0$$

Now, let $c=\cos(\alpha)$. From the previous equations:

$$8c^3-4c^2-4c+1=0\ ...(1)$$
$$4c^4+4c^3-7c+1=0\ ...(2)$$

Subtract the equations:

$$4c^4-4c^3+4c^2-3c=0$$

Since $c$ cannot be $0$ ($c=0$ doesn't fulfill (1)), we get

$$4c^3-4c^2+4c-3=0$$
$$8c^3-8c^2+8c-6=0\ ...(3)$$

Subtract (3) from (1):

$$4c^2-12c+7=0$$
$$4c^2-12c+9=2$$
$$(2c-3)^2=2$$
$$2c-3=\pm\sqrt2$$
$$2c=3\pm\sqrt2$$
$$c=\frac{3\pm\sqrt2}2$$
$$\cos(\frac{180^o}7)=\frac{3\pm\sqrt2}2$$

Since $\cos(\frac{180^o}7)\le1$, we get

$$\cos(\frac{180^o}7)=\frac{3-\sqrt2}2$$

But I substituted it to (1), and it doesn't fulfill the equation.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is this trolling?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I found the mistake when I read the question over.

Answer (score 2):

In the fifth line of the argument from $\cos(3\alpha)=-\cos(4\alpha)$, I made the mistake of turning $\cos(2\alpha)$ to $2\cos(\alpha)-1$, instead of the correct $2\cos^2(\alpha)-1$.

Now let's carry on, fixing the mistake:

$$(2\cos^2(\alpha)-1)(2\cos^2(\alpha)+\cos(\alpha)-1)=1-(2\cos^2(\alpha)-1)^2+2(1-\cos^2(\alpha))\cos(\alpha)$$
$$4\cos^4(\alpha)+2\cos^3(\alpha)-4\cos^2(\alpha)-\cos(\alpha)+1=1-(4\cos^4(\alpha)-4\cos^2(\alpha)+1)+2\cos(\alpha)-2\cos^3(\alpha)$$
$$4\cos^4(\alpha)+2\cos^3(\alpha)-4\cos^2(\alpha)-\cos(\alpha)=-4\cos^4(\alpha)+4\cos^2(\alpha)-1+2\cos(\alpha)-2\cos^3(\alpha)$$
$$8\cos^4(\alpha)+4\cos^3(\alpha)-8\cos^2(\alpha)-3\cos(\alpha)+1=0$$

Now, let $c=\cos(\alpha)$. From the previous equations:

$$8c^3-4c^2-4c+1=0\ ...(1)$$
$$8c^4+4c^3-8c^2-3c+1=0\ ...(2)$$

Subtract (1) from (2):

$$8c^4-4c^3-4c^2+c=0$$

Since $c$ cannot be $0$ ($c=0$ doesn't fulfill (1)), we get

$$8c^3-4c^2-4c+1=0\ ...(1)$$

I can't go further, so the value to find is the root of that equation which is in the interval $(0,1)$ (only one).